# How to install the latest kernel on an older release of Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint

I have Linux Mint 13 Maya installed on my PC and I noticed that my Windows Phone was not recognized by LM 13. I tried to manually compile a driver to support the device as instructed by a third party vendor, it worked although the device support was poor(limited file management and no sync capabilities).

I figured that a newer kernel would bring official driver support to Windows Phone devices.
Since my current PC configuration isn't ready for Linux Mint 17, I have no option but to stick to Mint 13. I'm not going to install LM 14,15,16 as they aren't LTS releases.

Now how do I obtain the latest kernel that I can install without breaking up my current PC setup?

Comment: Attempting to install the current kernel over Linux Mine 13 is a guaranteed way of breaking your current PC setup.  I also don't see ho upgrading the kernel will address your problem.

Comment: In what sense is your machine not ready for Mint 17 but is ready for a new kernel?  Why would you not install a release just because it isn't LTS?